# How to fix "The OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" has not been registered"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

Here's the code I'm using to register a linked server to SSAS:

```
USE [master];
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
    @server = N'ServerAlias',
    @srvproduct = N'',
    @provider= N'MSOLAP',
    @datasrc= N'ActualServerName',
    @catalog = N'DatabaseName';
```

When I attempt to run an MDX query using `OPENQUERY`, or if I use the Test Connection command in Management Studio after running the above code, I get the error:

> Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" has not been registered.

This is pretty strange as this provider is installed as part of SQL Server.

- It also fails on all other instances on the same box -- 5 total instances of 2008 R2 RTM and 2008 R2 SP1. I don't remember exactly, but 1 or 2 of the instances on the problem box may have been upgraded from 2008 to 2008 R2 at some point.
- It succeeded on a couple of other boxes using 2008 R2, including one box that has about a dozen total instances of 2005, 2008 R2 and 2012. I tried both 32-bit and 64-bit with success.

I looked at [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2555855) which describes the exact issue; however, there isn't a resolution that's applicable. Every other instance of this error I found on the internet was due to someone incorrectly defining the linked server, which also isn't applicable.

This is a development server (thankfully), so pretty much all options are on the table. Would a Repair fix this? It feels like something is awry in the registry.

(I'm asking for direction first, as I can't perform any maintenance myself due to lack of permissions.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SQL Server Analysis Services drivers aren't actually installed as a part of the normal SQL Server installation unless you install SSAS on the server.

You can download the MSOLAP driver from the [SQL Server feature pack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2735567) and install it.  Then you can create the linked server.  Don't forget to install the 64bit install if you have a 64bit SQL Server or the 32bit if you have a 32bit SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Search for msolap*.dll to find your installed providers and register them using `regsvr32`.

Examples follow (your file locations may vary):

```
C:\>regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\130\msolap130.dll"

C:\>regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\110\msolap110.dll"
```

And if you are using a 64-bit OS:

```
C:\>regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\120\msolap130.dll"
```

Also make sure that you are running the Command Prompt as **Administrator**