# Azure Managed Instance MSOLAP OLE DB connector

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

We have a managed Azure SQL instance, and trying to leverage it for some Azure AS documentation. Managed Azure supports `OPENROWSET` which was going to be used to access DMVs in the SSAS tabular model, but instead we get the following error:

```
Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" has not been registered.
```

Question is then, can MSOLAP OLE DB provider be installed on an Azure Managed SQL database, and if so how? Thanks!

Example query run on the managed instance:

```
SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET('MSOLAP','DATASOURCE=azure.windows.net/server;
     Initial Catalog=DataCatalog;',
    'SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_DIMENSIONS')
```

Comment: Check this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36001/how-to-fix-the-ole-db-provider-msolap-has-not-been-registered

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but this is an Azure Managed SQL instance... I cannot just remote into a server and run an executable.